# List index out of range error while processing data file

Tags: python

I have a series of data files [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uus53.png) containing 2 columns, where the first line is formatted differently than the remainder of the file. I'm trying to turn each of the 2 columns into their own lists (ignoring the first line), but I keep getting a 'list index out of range' error, and I can't figure out why..

I have *very* limited programming experience, so apologies for the mess of a code.

```
file_name_pre = 'spa000'
first_file = '7'
last_file = '28'
file_suffix = '.txt'
a = int(first_file)
b = int(last_file)
file_num = a
x_val = []
y_val = []

for i in range(a, a + 1):
    file = file_name_pre + str(file_num).zfill(2) + file_suffix
    hndl = open(str(file), 'rt')
    data = hndl.readlines()
    time = float(data[0])
    time_col.append(time)
    c = len(data)
    for j in range(1, c + 1):
        x = float(data[j].split()[0])  #error on this line
        x_val.append(x)
        y = float(data[j].split()[1])
        y_val.append(y)
hndl.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is in the following line `for j in range(1, c + 1)`, if you check [range doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) you will find that:

> range signature is as follow `range(start, stop[, step])` and the the last element is the smallest `start + i * step` greater than stop. When the step is not specified like in your case the last index will be `stop - 1`

`c` in your case is a list length: `len(data)` and since python lists are 0 index based, so the last valid index should be `c - 1` and considering the `range` logic you should replace:

`for j in range(1, c + 1)`

by:

`for j in range(1, c)`

Answer (score 1):

try replace this line

```
for j in range(1, c + 1):
```

to this

```
for j in range(1, c):
```

your **data** are starting from index 0 not 1

Comment: The first line should be skipped.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to that, but now I'm getting the same error for the line y = float(data[j].split()[1]). Also wouldn't that range now make it include the first line?

Comment: if first line should be skipped than Markus answer is correct

Comment: Yes, the first line will not be skipped. And your second exception most likely means that there are lines with only one column.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `range(1, c+1)` should read `range(1, c)`.

Comment: Yep. that worked, thanks. I was under the impression that the range function was not inclusive for the end value, can you explain why it's not cutting the last line off?

Comment: For example, `range(0,3)` will yield the numbers 0, 1, and 2. Indices start at 0, therefore your list should have 3 items. Think of the second number as the length of the list. This will work as long as you don't provide a step for range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative technique based on [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

File `file.txt`:

```
something
1. 11.
2. 22.
3. 33.
4. 44.
5. 54.
```

Script:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', skip_header=1, usecols=(0,1), dtype=np.float32, autostrip=True)
data = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1) # swap the axes

print data[0] # 1st line: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
print data[1] # 2nd line: [ 11.  22.  33.  44.  54.]
```

It's a clear and fast approach, feel free using it.